# Make password protected folder using python which cannot be copied/moved/deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x, password-protection, password-encryption

I have a folder (lets say folder-ABC) in my computer (lets say computer-1).

I wish to make a python program which will ask for password, the moment I try to copy/move/delete the folder-ABC in an external hard-drive.

I referred a few documentations that refers to folder locking. (example: https://pythonsecret.blogspot.com/2017/08/how-to-create-folder-lock-with-password.html)

When the folder-ABC is locked, it only gets disappeared from the working directory.
I can still copy the entire directory in an external hard-drive, recreate the directory in computer-2, run the same python program in computer-2, and make the locked folder-ABC visible once again in computer-2.

However, right at the beginning, I need to ensure that the the folder-ABC does not get copied to any external drive and ask for password to do so.

Can anyone please let me know whether is there any documentation available which can help me out to do so ?

Comment: The author of the page you link is just toggling the `hidden` flag of the folder and renaming it. You can do that manually, without a password. The password is a kind of misdirection. There's no real security there.

Comment: There’s no way Python can do much for you here. This is a feature the underlying file system and/or OS needs to provide. Some external program like Python can’t add security which isn’t in those fundamentals.

Comment: The closest thing you could get to this in python is to make a script that can encrypt files in a directory and decrypt them if it receives the right password. This is what's known as a "bad idea" and you'd be better off looking into if your OS can password protect folders.